# Microsoft Edge Translation Tool

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I have, what I think, is a strange problem.

I have been creating a webpage for my site that, whenever I refresh the page, prompts Microsoft Edge (but not Chrome or FireFox) to ask me if I would like to translate the page from Portuguese and sometimes French.
I have been going through the HTML to identify what is causing this issue and I have discovered the following block of code is causing the issue:

```
<p class="ltol__pub">
  This website is a publication of the livingtheOKlife company.
</p>
```

You may at this point be thinking that the name "livingtheOKlife" is causing the issue. However, I have used this name on multiple webpages in the past and never had this problem before. Furthermore, if I use a different line for the paragraph:

```
<p class="ltol__pub">
  This website was designed and created by the livingtheOKlife
  company.
</p>
```

The issue is resolved.

It is not an problem if I have to use the second line instead of the first. I can sleep at night if that is to be the case. However, I would very much like to know if anyone knows what may be causing the translate prompt to appear?

... and before you say it, I have included `<html lang="en">` in the document.

... and I'm also aware this could be a bug, but I cannot find any record of it anywhere.

Comment: It's probably just an odd edge case with the translation engine being a bit overzealous and detecting a language erroneously. Short of reporting it to the browser vendors via their bug reporting channels, there's not much you'll be able to do about this unless the underlying heuristics that cause this content to trigger a translation request are fixed.

Comment: @esqew I thought this may be the case. Even if this is just an issue with Microsoft Edge, I don't feel completely comfortable publishing a webpage that prompts translation, for no reason, every time you visit it. So it was worth asking, just in case. Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 1):

Add `translate="no"` in the `<html>` tag of your page. Also add `<meta>` tag with `name="google"` and `content="notranslate"` in the `<head>`. This tag should also work on Edge.

```html
<html lang="en" translate="no">
 <head>
   <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
 </head>  
...
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I also tried adding it to the <p> tag itself, but to no avail. Thank you for offering a potential fix though!

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: `<meta name="google" content="notranslate">` is working on Edge which is weird.  May be because of the chromium engine.